# why disabled item is still checkable in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want a listView with some items and all of them could be checked. But if the first item is not checked then the other item is not enabled, of course, they should not be checkable at the time.
So I extend ListView to MyListView like this:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {

public MyListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Init();
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Init();
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Init();
}

private void Init() {
    setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,array ));
    setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            SparseBooleanArray posArray = getCheckedItemPositions();
            boolean bChecked = false;
            if( null != posArray ) {
                for( int i = 0; i < posArray.size(); i++ ) {
                    int nIdx = posArray.keyAt(i);
                    if( nIdx == 0 ) {
                        bChecked = posArray.get(nIdx);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if( position == 0 ) {
                bChecked = !bChecked;

                for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
                    getChildAt(i).setEnabled(!bChecked);
                }
            } 
        }
    });
}

private String[] array = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" };
```

}

and then I got the problem: disabled items still are checkable, is there something wrong? How should I do it?
Thanks.

---

Actually,the problem is done by  pawan yadav's suggestion. Bellow is my code, wish to help anyone meet the same problem.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

in activity's onCreate method:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
String [] datas = new String[36]; // generate you data here 
final boolean [] status = new boolean[36]; // generate you check status here 

final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(datas, status); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter );

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if( position== 0 || status[0] ) {
            status[position] = !status[positioin];
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
parentLayout.addView(listView);
```

listview_checkedtextview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
/>
```

activity's inner class:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public MyAdapter( final String [] datas, final boolean [] status ) {
    this.datas = datas;
    this.status = status;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datas.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( null == convertView ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_checkedtextview, null);
        convertView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    } 

    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
    checkedTextView.setText(datas[position]);
    checkedTextView.setChecked(status[position]);
    checkedTextView.setEnabled( position == 0 ? true : status[0]);

    return convertView;
}

private String [] datas;
private boolean [] status;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
}
```

Comment: you should implement getview() of adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `setClickable(boolean)` to make it not clickable instead of `setEnabled(boolean)`